# Why does return inside finally gives empty dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, exception, try-catch

I want to keep a track of exceptions inside a dictionary and return the same. However when I do so, finally block gives me an empty dictionary. The logic pretty much works for scalars. Can someone explain the behavior please.

In scalar context:

```
def test():
    temp = 1
    try:
        raise ValueError("sdfs")
    except:
        temp = 2
    finally:
        temp = temp + 3
        return temp
test()
5
```

With dictionary:

```
def test():
    temp = dict()
    try:
        raise ValueError("something")
    except Exception as error:
        print("error is :{}".format(error))
        temp['except'] = "something" + error
    finally:
        return temp

test()
error is : something
{}
```

Comment: Where is the code that prints the final result?

Comment: Note that Python does not have a 'scalar context' concept. You are thinking of Perl there, perhaps.

Comment: yes...you got the context though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You caused another exception to be raised in the exception handler, which is swallowed because there is a `finally` handler that *returns from the function*.

You can't just concatenate an exception object and a string, so an additional `TypeError` is raised, and the assignment to the dictionary is never reached.

Converting the exception to a string first works:

```
>>> def test():
...     temp = dict()
...     try:
...         raise ValueError("something")
...     except Exception as error:
...         print("error is :{}".format(error))
...         temp['except'] = "something" + str(error)
...     finally:
...         return temp
...
>>> test()
error is :something
{'except': 'somethingsomething'}
```

From the [`try` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The `try` clause is executed, including any `except` and `else` clauses. **If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved**. The `finally` clause is executed. If there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the `finally` clause. If the `finally` clause raises another exception, the saved exception is set as the context of the new exception. **If the `finally` clause executes a `return` or `break` statement, the saved exception is discarded**[.]

(Bold emphasis mine).

Answer (score 4):

The line `"something" + error` raises an error which is discarded because you returned from `finally`. Due to the error the assignment to the dictionary `temp` is never performed giving the impression that nothing happens.

This is stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) for `try-except`:

> If finally is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The `try`
>   clause is executed, including any except and else clauses. *If an
>   exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the
>   exception is temporarily saved*. The finally clause is executed. If
>   there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the finally
>   clause. If the finally clause raises another exception, the saved
>   exception is set as the context of the new exception. *If the finally
>   clause executes a return or break statement, the saved exception is
>   discarded.*

<sup><sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup></sup>

Without an error (i.e `temp['except'] = error` you get the expected behavior:

```
>>> test()
error is :something
{'except': ValueError('something')}
```